# How to get previous month in elixir

Tags: datetime, calendar, erlang, elixir

How can I get the previous month without using a package or library in elixir?

For example, if the current date is `2018-01-25`, I will get `2017-12-25`.
Or If the current date is `2018-03-31`, I will get `2018-02-28` (2018 is not a leap year)

Comment: I've deleted my answer. See Aleksei's instead, which is much better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer by @Sheharyar is almost there, the only difference you need to subtract the maximum of days *in both* months:

```ex
defmodule Dating do
  def previous_month(%Date{day: day} = date) do
    days = max(day, (Date.add(date, -day)).day)
    Date.add(date, -days)
  end
end
```

Works for all cases:

```ex
iex|1 ▶ Dating.previous_month(~D[2018-03-31])
#⇒ ~D[2018-02-28]
iex|2 ▶ Dating.previous_month(~D[2018-03-01])
#⇒ ~D[2018-02-01]
iex|3 ▶ Dating.previous_month(~D[2018-01-02])
#⇒ ~D[2017-12-02]
```

Comment: Wow, that's actually much better. I'll keep my answer up for future reference, but I think this is what should be used.

Comment: Nevermind, I deleted it anyways, since this is the superior solution. (And also for the [`Disciplined`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined) badge :P)

Comment: @Sheharyar ROFL; actually this answer is fully inspired by yours (and my pain in the bleeding eyes when I saw Timex implementation.)

Comment: Wow, thanks for this great answer! I was about to use Timex library as my last resort until I tried this. It's pain using such library but you need only one of its function. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Guys! Could you please help me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53512997/get-next-month-in-elixir)?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Timex](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex) library

```
iex(1)> ~D[2018-01-25] |> Timex.shift(months: -1)
~D[2017-12-25]

iex(2)> ~D[2018-03-31] |> Timex.shift(months: -1)
~D[2018-02-28]
```

Comment: But I want to do it without using a library.

Comment: Yes, right. That's too complex, you'll need to create some helper to do it. It is equivalent of having a library, but made by yourself. Let's wait for other answers, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I looked at Timex library source code, I found it too complex to make Timex.shift function. I will now consider using Timex library. Thanks for the answer.